# what if a Timer falls behind schedule

Tags: java, timer, schedule, threadpoolexecutor

I am using a `java.util.Timer` class. I use it to execute repetitive tasks. (e.g. a polling mechanism that checks a status every second).

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Poller(), 0, pollingInterval);
```

**The problem case is: timers can fall behind**. e.g. If they need to execute every second, and the task takes 2 seconds to execute.

The documentation says that the timer will try to catch-up. e.g. Suddenly if the tasks only takes half a second to execute, it will speed up.

First of all, I am wondering, **is there a *built-in* way to detect if it's running behind**.

But anyway, I am looking for a way to disable the catching-up behavior.
If it falls behind, **I just want it to skip a couple of cycles.**

(I've also used a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` for similar tasks. It has more options, and maybe that can be the solution. But it's a bit too overwhelming to find it.)

## EDIT:

Now that I think about it, I think the way to do it with a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, is to use the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` method, which uses an interval **between** task execution.

Still, is there a way to achieve the same with a `Timer`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care if the timer falls behind, why not use a simple while loop with a Thread.sleep, such as:

```
while(condition) {
    // do work here
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
}
```

If this falls behind due to OS scheduling constraints, it will never try to make up the time that was lost. It will always delay for at least the amount of time you specify. Remember, simple is better than complex.